# Can not update user profile property using CSOM for SharePoint onprem

Tags: csom, user-profile, jsom, sharepoint-on-prem

I am trying to update user profile property using CSOM for SharePoint onpremise, but the value was not updated to the property. There is no error exception.
I try with JSOM but it does not work also.
Have anyone meet this issue like me?

```
string accountName = "domain\\userloginname";
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url);
NetworkCredential ncr = new NetworkCredential(accountName, securePassword);
clientContext.Credentials = ncr;

var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(accountName, "AboutMe", "Value by CSOM");
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: which version of SharePoint OnPrem are you using ?

Comment: @GautamSheth It is SharePoint 2019, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, SP2019.